# Is it possible to change MFP(mobile first platform) base URL?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Current MFP URL looks like http://hostname:portNo/Runtimename/adapter/adaptername/path

Is it possible to change base path to
http://localhost:10080/travel/1.1/adapters/flight/listflight

soon after runtime name Travel I want to add give version number or some valuable name.

Answer (score 3):

MFP client SDK will construct the complete URL based on the values in wlclient.properties. 
The first part of the URL < http://hostname:portNo/Runtimename/> can be different as long you take care of the routing or redirection at your end.
But the change you are asking is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you can put a web server like Apache in front of it, you might be able to use mod_rewrite to do some of that.